# java moving in a two dimensional matrix

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have a two dimensional array int matrix[numNodes][numArcs]. This is an Incidence matrix.

Now, if we wish to add an arc, we have to check those nodes exist and the arc does not exist. This part works well. The following thing i need to do, is find an empty column to add the arc. So the matrix is full of zeros at the beginning . So its simple, you search each column until you find a column full of zeros. Sounds simple but its now working. This part of the code is the following:

```
    outerloop:
    for (int i = 0; i < numArcs; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < numNodes; j++){
            if (matriz[j][i] != 0)
                break;
                //It finds a number != 0 so it should move to the next column 

            //If it gets here, the whole column was full of zeros
            column = i; 
            key = true;
            break outerloop;
        }
    }
```

I use the key to know i found the column, because if i dont its because the matrix is full and i need to duplicate it. Thats another issue non-related to this problem.

Now, i tried to figure out the problem and i notice the following: its only checking these positions:

```
01
02
03
03
```

As you can see, its just checking the first position of each column and not going all the way down how it should. To me it makes no sense. NumNode is 10 in my example, so it should go all the way down.

Edit:
My exact example
the matrix is like this:

```
 -1  -1 -1 0 0 0 ....
  0   1  0 0 0 ...
  0   0  1 0 0 .....
```

So when it reaches the fourth column, it reads that zero and return thats the empty column. 
It does the same for the next n arcs I added. the following arcs i add don't touch the first row any more. 
thanks for the help

Comment: is your `matriz` variable of type `double[][]` in any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < numArcs; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < numNodes; j++){
        if (matriz[j][i] != 0)
            break;
            //It finds a number != 0 so it should move to the next column 

        //If it gets here, the whole column was full of zeros
        column = i; 
        key = true;
        break outerloop;
    }
}
```

What if in the inner loop, you don't break for the first time.. You will store `i` into column without checking other rows for that column..

You can better use a boolean flag variable to check what you want..

```
    int[][] matrix = new int[5][4];
    boolean columnEmpty = true;
    int column = 0;
    boolean key = false;

    matrix[0][0] = -1;
    matrix[0][1] = -1;
    matrix[1][1] = 1;
    matrix[1][2] = -1;
    matrix[2][2] = -1;

    outerloop: for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            columnEmpty = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
                if (matrix[j][i] != 0) {
                   columnEmpty = false;
                   break;
                }

            }
            if (columnEmpty) {
                // If we are here.. then flag was never set to `true`. 
                // So, all the rows for that column was Zero..
                column = i; 
                key = true;
                break outerloop;
            }

        }

    System.out.println("Column : " + column);
```

Comment: let me try that and ill let you know in a few

Comment: instead of using `break`, you can even check within the loop condition : `boolean colEmpty = true; for (int j=0; j<numNodes && colEmpty; j++)  colEmpty = matriz[j][i] != 0;` (no `if` and `break`)

Comment: @YanickRochon.. Yeah that can also be done.. But, will not make much difference in performance.. Still it is a valid solution..

Comment: @RohitJain, yes, it is checked in the loop condition :) as soon as `colEmpty` is false, it will break

Comment: @RohitJain, I'm just suggesting because `flag` is not intuitive for a variable name :) and I'm a strong believer that `break` is somewhat of an obsolete keyword in Java (except in `switch`, but still as an OO language, those can be avoided too)

Comment: Still same problem, it only checks the first row of the column. i dont know if i am missing something. I does move the column, but it reads the first row of the column and it reads and zero and it exit the loop

Comment: @Alessandroempire.. Does your first row have non-zero value?? Because it should work.. Check the code again.. Notice the closing braces..

Comment: There, i added the example. let me check the code again. it must be something silly.

Comment: @Alessandroempire.. It is working for me.. I'm getting column value `3` for your above example..

Comment: @RohitJain can you check that J is going all the way down, and if it is, pass me that code. i am desperate

Comment: @Alessandroempire.. Yeah it is going with this code.. If I put a zero value in 1st row, and non-zero in the 2nd row, it is not returning that column.. You can check with the latest code..

Comment: @Alessandroempire.. Paste the above code in your main().. You will get what you want..

Comment: @RohitJain I copied and pasted what you posted and it work. Weird... but thanks at a lot!

Comment: @RohitJain yeah was getting to that. Was checking the matrix was perfect.